# Springboot @PutMapping 405 error from postman

Tags: java, spring-boot

Springboot version 2.1.8.RELEASE

> controller

```
    @PutMapping("/sample/{id}")
    public Sample update(@PathVariable String id, @RequestBody Sample s){
        s.setId(id);
        return sampleService.update(s);
    }
```

> postman

PUT    http://localhost:8080/sample/sspa01

return

```
{
    "status": 405,
    "error": "Method Not Allowed",
    "message": "Request method 'PUT' not supported",
    "path": "/sample/sspa01"
}
```

Thanks to let me know how to fix this problem

Comment: try to change `@PathVariable("id")`

Comment: @michalk thanks, but this does work

Comment: @Marco make sure you are making a PUT request with endpoint, can you share the image of postman request?

Comment: Please add your complete Controller class

Comment: Check with GetMapping to know if the problem is with method PUT or with wrong URL. It may be also permission from spring security, sometime URL accepts localhost without http or 127.0.0.1 ....

Answer (score 0):

In here  can solve this by defining an explicit mapping for PUT, in the existing method mapping

Try this one

```
  //@PutMapping("/sample/{id}")
```

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/sample/{id}", produces = "application/json",  method=RequestMethod.PUT)
```

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/sample/{id}", produces = "application/json",  method=RequestMethod.PUT)
    public Sample update(@PathVariable("id") String id, @RequestBody Sample s){
        s.setId(id);
        return sampleService.update(s);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the url was not part of `permitAll()` once added it worked fine, can you check your `@EnableWebSecurity` config for below method

```
  @Bean
  SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).